# How to Achieve Mysql Operation UNHEX & HEX with Django Model Database API

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

thanks for coming in.I was just planning on integrating an audio fingerprint Python Module into Django Framework. I encountered this problem when rewrite its database operation. One of Mysql command looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO %s (%s, %s, %s) values (%%s, UNHEX(%%s), %s);
```

And I didn't find similar method for Django.Models to achieve that and Hex() as well.If anyone knows how to do that, please help.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022994/1862154

It can be done by implement a new field type and implement a `get_placeholder` function